# Creating ADS AEP using VFP

Tags: visual-foxpro, advantage-database-server

My understanding is that AEP can be developed in any language but I couldn't find any sample for VFP, only VB, C++, etc

As an initial project I wanted to try something simple like send a Product Code and get back the current Stock value from a free ADS table (in fact a VFP table accessed via ADS) + errors handling.

I have good VFP experience (exe applications using ODBC) but nothing in this area (web access).

I made some researches on internet but even for the Startup/Shutdown (part of the template) I found different number of parameters to be passed, so I am confused.

A sample of Startup/Shutdown + a simple function which access a table and get some data (i.e SELECT Field1 FROM MyTable WHERE Field2=<My_Input_Value>), written in VFP for ADS V10.10 would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If I were you I'd create the Advantage Extended Procedure using Visual C# with Visual Studio .NET as you will be able to use the templates provided with ADS. It doesn't matter that your client applications are written in Visual FoxPro.

Comment: @dougwoodrow Thank you Doug. I want to use VFP because I know it very well. For Visual C# I have to learn all. Can you give me a template/simple sample from Visual C#, maybe I can get a better understanding and eventually I will be able to transpose it in VFP?

Comment: C# isn't a difficult language to learn, but you may well find that it's simpler to create a standard SQL Stored Procedure instead. SQL scripts can be surprisingly versatile.

There are worked examples by Cary Jensen here, showing both SQL stored procedures and also AEPs created in various languages:
https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?devguide_writing_stored_procedures.htm

Comment: I read the AEP samples from ADS helps but all are focused only on the user function (Get10Percent, etc). I want to see how are built the Startup/Shutdown sample functions from the Advantage template. From my understanding this template should be part of Visual Studio but I couldn't find it in VS2019 or VS2012 (the older version available for download). Any help in this direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you install the Advantage .NET Data Provider? 
The templates should be available as "AdvantageAEP" under File->New->Project after installing the .NET data provider.

https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?dotnet_installing_the_advantage_net_data_provider.htm

Comment: I installed but only V10.1 because I am working with this version of the server. Now I installed Advantage .NET Data Provider 11.1 and this time the template is visible under VS2012. Most likely 10.1 requires an older version of VS. No I have at least something to work on and try to transpose into VFP. Thank you Doug.

Comment: You can get the v10.1 .NET data provider here: https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=20&Release=16&Product=4&Platform=11